# Chrome >= Beta vs. Stable from security aspect

Tags: google-chrome, security

While I always read the huge list of security related fixes for Stable in the Chromium blog, I never see the Beta or any other version getting these fixes. As in: There is no such "announcement" in the blog. I know the development is open-source, but there are no commit numbers at the announcement to track them back. (Like if that commit arrived into Beta at the same time / sooner than that.)

My question is:
The beta version got the exact same security fixes at the same time (or even sooner)?
Or the stable version is more secure?

Comment: I dont know the answer, but you have to assume the beta is insecure as old bugs may have been introduced, as well as new ones.

Comment: The “beta” moniker is simply a tag applied to certain builds in the revision tree, as is the “stable” moniker. It’s not like betas are from a separate branch; stable releases are simply further along in the timeline: `ver 1 2 3 4 5 beta 6 7 8 stable 9 10 beta 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 beta 19 stable 20 21 22 beta 23 beta 24 25 26 27 28 29 beta 30 stable…`

Comment: My feeling is that security measures are introduced in beta (and dev) first and then, after being found effective and not destabilizing, carried over to stable.

Comment: @Keltari absolutely disagree. I suppose that most hackers will check for the widest usage. Let's say 40% of the users run Windows with Chrome, 15% run Safari on a Mac, only 0,00001% run Windows with Chrome Dev. I would strongly recommend using a system which is rare in it's configuration. Am I wrong?